# Prove by induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $, $(1+\frac {1} {2})^n\geq 1+ \frac{n} {2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I have been messing around with this one for a while, I thought of using a binomial expansion like  $(1+\dfrac {1} {2})^{(n+1)} = (1+ \dfrac {1} {2})^n(1+ \dfrac {1} {2})=(1+\dfrac {1} {2})\sum _{i=0}^{n} \begin{pmatrix}
n \\
i 
\end{pmatrix} [(1^{n-i}(\dfrac {1} {2})^{i}] $ But I still don't know how to use that to prove the claim that  for all $ k \in \mathbb{N} $,  $(1+\dfrac {1} {2})^n\geq 1+ \dfrac{n} {2}$

Maybe I could go a different route but I'm having trouble seeing it.
Thanks!

Comment: Remember that when you're trying to look at $(1+\frac12)^{n+1}$ you have the result for $(1+\frac12)^n$ available to use; rather than using the binomial expansion, you can say that $(1+\frac12)^n(1+\frac12)\geq (1+\frac n2)(1+\frac12)$.

Answer (score 3):

Well you are trying to use induction so you should apply the induction hypothesis. In particular, notice that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1} = \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right) \geq \left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right) = \cdots$$

Answer (score 3):

The binomial expansion will prove it without induction[*].

$(1+ \frac 1 2)^n = 1 + n\frac 12 + .... \text{more terms; all positive} ... \ge 1 + \frac n 2$ with equality holding only for n = 1.

But you asked specifically for a proof by induction.  So the induction step is:

$(1 + \frac 1 2)^{n+1} = (1 + \frac 1 2)^n(1 + \frac 1 2) \ge (1 + \frac n 2)(1 + \frac 1 2) = 1 + 1\cdot\frac n 2 + \frac 1 2 \cdot 1 + \frac n 4 = 1 + \frac {n+1} 2 + \frac n 4 > 1 + \frac {n+1} 2$

====

[*] although it has been pointed out that the proof of the binomial theorem required induction in its proof.  (I think).  So perhaps the declaration "without induction" is debatable.  I'd argue it is a valid claim as induction isn't being invoked in this proof.  But it could also be argued "without induction" means "independent of induction" (although I wouldn't interpret it this way) and that isn't the case

Comment: Is using the binomial theorem really proving it without induction though? The binomial theorem is often proved via induction.

Comment: True... but I'm taking the binomial theorem as a given.  So we are proving *this* without induction but *someone else* proved the binomial theorem with induction.  So *we* aren't using induction; someone else is.  How's that for weaseling?  But yes, you do have a point.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Bernoulli's inequality $$(1+x)^n\geqslant 1+nx$$ which is true for every integer $n\geqslant 0$ and real $x\geqslant -1$

Comment: OP specifically requests a proof by induction.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki you can very easily prove the above inequality via induction.

Comment: @rubik Yes, but then that's the OP's question again.

Answer (score 1):

$n \in \mathbb{N} $, $(1+\frac {1} {2})^n\geq 1+ \frac{n} {2}$

The base case when $n=1$

$(1+\frac {1} {2})^1\geq 1+ \frac{1} {2}$

suppose when $n=p$ the statement is true

$i.e$ $$(1+\frac {1} {2})^p\geq 1+ \frac{p} {2}$$

now

$$(1+\frac {1} {2})^p(1+\frac{1}{2})\geq (1+ \frac{p} {2})(1+\frac{1}{2})$$

$$(1+\frac {1} {2})^{p+1}\geq 1+ \frac{p} {2}+\frac{1} {2}+\frac{p}{4}$$

$$(1+\frac {1} {2})^{p+1}>1+ \frac{p+1} {2}$$

therefore

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $, $(1+\frac {1} {2})^n\geq 1+ \frac{n} {2}$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @RFZ 's answer:
Suppose the base case of $k=0$ for which $(1+1/2)^k\geq 1+k/2$. Then this becomes $$\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^0\geq 1+\cfrac{0}{2} \implies 1\geq 1$$ as required. Now let $k=1$. Then:
$$\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^1 \geq 1+\cfrac{1}{2} \implies \cfrac{3}{2}\geq\cfrac{3}{2}$$ which is true.
Now assume this is true for some arbitrary $k=n, n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is our inductive hypothesis. Then assume the following inequality
$$\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^n \geq 1+\cfrac{n}{2}$$ holds.
Which produces:
$$\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^n\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg) \geq \bigg(1+\cfrac{n}{2}\bigg)\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)$$
$$\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^{n+1} \geq 1 + \cfrac{1}{2} + \cfrac{n}{2} + \cfrac{n}{4}$$
$$= 1+ \cfrac{n+1}{2}+\cfrac{n}{4} \geq 1+\cfrac{n+1}{2}$$
So $$\bigg(1+\cfrac{1}{2}\bigg)^{n+1} \geq 1+\cfrac{n+1}{2}$$
So in fact this holds for all $k=n+1$ since $\cfrac{n}{4}\geq0$. Then by induction we conclude that this holds for all $k\geq 0, k\in\mathbb{N}$, and we are done.